# Expression type bool is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

The following code is used to work in `Swift 2`:

```
let endpoint = EndpointManager(endpoint: userType == .Pro ? .ProFollowing(identifier, url) : .FanFollowing(identifier, url), method: .get, parameters: nil)
```

Now it gives the error:

> Expression type bool is ambiguous without more context

The following solution worked for me:

```
var following : Endpoint
if userType == .pro {
        following = Endpoint.proFollowing(identifier,url)
}
else {
        following = Endpoint.fanFollowing(identifier,url)
}
let endpoint = EndpointManager(endpoint: following, method: .get, parameters: nil)
```

Comment: Add more code like what is `userType`.

Comment: You shouldn't using a long line code like that. So terrible. 
Please separate the code first.

Comment: Write in like this : let endpoint = EndpointManager(endpoint: (userType == .Pro) ? (.ProFollowing(identifier, url)) : (.FanFollowing(identifier, url)), method: .get, parameters: nil).

Comment: Doesn't solve the error

Comment: This code works fine for me if I create the types that it requires. I suspect some of your enum cases were renamed to lead-lowercase. Check that `.Pro` isn't not `.pro` and `.ProFollowing` isn't now `.proFollowing`, etc. Otherwise, break this down to an example that includes the definitions of the types (I suspect that creating that example will solve your problem)

Comment: @PujaJadhav So basically it's just as @RobNapier said -_- Meaning this dirty statement would have worked too `let endpoint = EndpointManager(endpoint: userType == .pro ? .proFollowing(identifier, url) : .fanFollowing(identifier, url), method: .get, parameters: nil)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap bool parameter by parenthesis:

```
let isProFollowing = userType == .Pro ? .ProFollowing(identifier, url)
let following: YourEnumType = isProFollowing ? .ProFollowing(identifier, url) : .FanFollowing(identifier, url)
let endpoint = EndpointManager(endpoint: following, method: .get, parameters: nil)
```

colon sign confuses your XCode

Comment: @PujaJadhav I've changed the code. Use my updated post

Comment: @Vyacheslav Swift 4 supports non-parenthesized inline ifs.

Comment: @staticVoidMan from time to time the expression might be too complicated to parse.

Comment: @Vyacheslav I hate inline ifs so I avoid them but your answer states it's not allowed/possible. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @staticVoidMan do you mean the `let following = `  type definition?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I mean, something like this is possible: `let test = doSomething(test: true ? "True" : "False", and: "Next argument")`.